# ASP.NET MVC Intentional Ajax Failure

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I am making an ajax call to my controller which is going to perform a long operation.  The operation can fail for many reasons or succeed.  If I want to force the failure code of my ajax call to execute ("error"), what do I need to do in my controller before returning?  Just throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an exception will lead to status code = 500 which will invoke the error handler, so it should be enough.